# Setting a session variable in PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

After a user clicks a div this javascript function runs:

```
$('.test').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"id": "<?php echo $rows['id']?>"},
            success:function(data){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to pass in an ID associated with the div the user clicks into my ajax.php file where this code runs:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //connect to db here
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
?>
```

However this is not working. To expand further what I did to pass get the `rows['id']` variable is run this SQL code:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id = '$id'";
$results_select = $conn->query($sql_select);
```

I then outputted a bunch of divs with id's corresponding to them:

```
<?php
    while ($select_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results_select))
    {
        echo "<div class = 'test'></div>";
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use data attributes:

Try:

```
<?php
    while ($select_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results_select))
    {
        echo "<div data-id='".$rows['id']."' class = 'test'></div>";
    }
?>
```

js:

```
$('.test').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"id": $(this).attr('data-id')},//fetch the data attribute 
            success:function(data){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately still receiving this error: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']?>''`

Comment: in my code i don't have any `<?php echo $rows['id']?>` copy my code exacly

Comment: I edited the code above, I located where the error was occuring and it was in my WHERE statement: `WHERE id = '$id'";` From my understanding there is nothing wrong with that syntax

Comment: so i know the id isnt being stored into the session variable

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JS code for  `data: {"id": "<?php echo $rows['id']?>"}`. This line may not be able to pass your actual value so store it into *div* with *id* attribute and get it by jQuery and pass it.

**JS:**

```
$('.test').click(function(e)
{
    dataValue = $(this).attr('id');//Get user clicked div id attribute value...
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"id": dataValue},
        success:function(data){
            window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

With above JS code you need to make some change for PHP code as well:

```
while ($select_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results_select))
{
    echo "<div class = 'test' id='". $select_rows['id'] ."'></div>";
}
```

Please confirm this code by `print_r($_POST);` on *AJAX* post handler page. This will print the *POST* data requested by *AJAX* code.

Let me know if there is any concern regarding this.